# Mono for Android: How to query empty table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, xamarin

I need to fill database, but before I will insert record I need to check that no same record in table. Right now table is empty. RawQuery returns Exception.

```
Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteCursor sqlitecursor = (Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteCursor)sqlite.RawQuery("select count(*) as rws from cells where CellID="+Cell.ToString(), null);
```

Comment: 1. What is the exception message? 2. Does the table exist?

Comment: Thank's... I've forgot to copy new (with cells table) database file to device.